# I am getting an error in Oracle about a command not properly ending

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do a multi table insert but for some reason I am getting an error.  I looked online and tried adding a semicolan and that didnt work.

The error is SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Here is my code

```
Insert Into EMP (empno,ename,job,mgr,sal,deptno)
Value    (4600,'BOB','CONSULT',4699,900,60),                                                
(5300,'AILEEN','MANAGER',7839,1800,40),
(9873,'RYAN','CONSULT',4699,800,50)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: value needs to be plural

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot perform several inserts in one statement. You have to write separate inserts for each of them, e.g.

```
insert into table_1 (...) values (...);
insert into table_1 (...) values (...);
etc.
```

Also, note that it's `values`, not `value`.

Comment: Okay, I thought they changed it in the most recent version of Oracle but I guess I was wrongly informed.  Thank you for your timely response.

Comment: You can do multiple inserts in one statement, see link here http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=209

Comment: @stevo Thanks, I didn't know that. The syntax is weird, though :)

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this command to insert all the records in a single statement

```
Insert all Into EMP (empno,ename,job,mgr,sal,deptno)
Values    (4600,'BOB','CONSULT',4699,900,60)
Into EMP (empno,ename,job,mgr,sal,deptno)
values (5300,'AILEEN','MANAGER',7839,1800,40)
Into EMP (empno,ename,job,mgr,sal,deptno)
values (9873,'RYAN','CONSULT',4699,800,50)
select * from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `INSERT INTO...SELECT ..FROM dual` where you use a `UNION ALL` between each select:

```
insert into EMP (empno,ename,job,mgr,sal,deptno)
select 4600,'BOB','CONSULT',4699,900,60
from dual
union all
select 5300,'AILEEN','MANAGER',7839,1800,40
from dual
union all
select 9873,'RYAN','CONSULT',4699,800,50
from dual;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d89a/1)

Or you can use:

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO emp (empno, ename, job, mgr, sal, deptno)
         VALUES (4600, 'BOB', 'CONSULT', 4699, 900, 60)
    INTO emp (empno, ename, job, mgr, sal, deptno)
         VALUES (5300, 'AILEEN', 'MANAGER', 7839, 1800, 40)
    INTO emp (empno, ename, job, mgr, sal, deptno)
         VALUES (9873, 'RYAN', 'CONSULT', 4699, 800, 50)
SELECT * 
FROM dual;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1a002/1)

Comment: Is there a reason to use this way over the way that was given above?

Comment: @AdamHalegua there is no reason, I was just showing that there are multiple ways to perform this operation. It really depends on what way you want to use.

Comment: Oh okay, I was just double checking.  I just want to make sure I fully understand this.  Thanks for you responses.

Comment: @AdamHalegua If you find any of the answers useful, then be sure to accept via the checkmark on the left of it.